# How do I get data out of JSON object withouth knowing the names

Tags: javascript, json, blockchain

Hi I have a javascript object that looks like this:

```
    {"_balance":"1500","texts":{
                                "0x4b8ca107efbc8b096c011f64d2c2d7aebdaec7fe": {"Best":"200","first one":"0"},
                                "0x7901b2b9caaeff5478d14873c39765373a48f890":{"number one !!!!1111":"1500"}}}
```

I can get `objName.texts` out of the object.

Which leaves me with:

```
  {"0x4b8ca107efbc8b096c011f64d2c2d7aebdaec7fe":{"Best":"200","first one":"0"},
   "0x7901b2b9caaeff5478d14873c39765373a48f890":{"number one !!!!1111":"1500"}}
```

It's a map of addresses with all the messages they left and the amount of points the message has. Now i need to get the messages out and sort them ascending by points but I don't know where to begin.

I'm not looking for a complete answer. Just a way to get the values out individually and put them in an array. I have no clue where to begin...

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Object.values(objName.texts)

Comment: `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, and/or `Object.entries()` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use syntax like that:

```
   Object.keys(jsonData['texts']).forEach(function(key) {
        var value = jsonData['texts'][key];
        console.log(key + ':');
        console.log(value);
    });
```

Please note that value is still an object, thats why I `console.log` it separately.

Comment: Thanks I got one step closer but the value is undefined
```0x4b8ca107efbc8b096c011f64d2c2d7aebdaec7fe: undefined
0x7901b2b9caaeff5478d14873c39765373a48f890: undefined```

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake... should be `var value = jsonData.texts[key];` or `jsonData['texts'][key]` (basically the same, but let's stay in one convension, edited

Answer (score 1):

There are three handy methods that could be helpful here:

- Object.keys(objName.texts) - return array of keys
- Object.values(objName.texts) - return array of values
- Object.entries(objName.texts) - return array of [key, value]